# Issue on how to call route for a mochajs npm test

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I'm trying to create a test for a route in mochajs however i'm having trouble wrapping my around it, the goal is to call the route and then display a text which the test till match if it displays the text or an error, Thank You In Advance.

test.js

```
const assert = require('chai').assert;
const app = require('../app');

dashboardAuthTest = authTest();

before(function(){
  server = app.listen(3000);
});

describe('App', function(){

  describe('authTest()', function(done){
    it('authTest should not allow unauthenticated user', function(){
      router.get('/dashboard');
      assert.equal(dashboardAuthTest, 'Please Login');
    });
  });
});

after(async () => {
  require('../app').stop();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure if this it, but try putting the ‘done’ in the ‘it’ block as such, instead of the describe
block. And finish the it block with the done call. That’s just how I have my written.

```
describe('GET /', () => {
  it('foo', function(done) {
      chai.expect(body).to.equal(something);
      done();
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm able to make it work but i'm not sure if it really test the route or not

Comment: here's the code i put in: describe('Dashboard Authentication', function() {
    it('should return Please Login', function(done) {
      request(router)
        .get('/dashboard')
        .expect('error_msg', 'Please Login')
        done()
    });
  });

Comment: Maybe throw a console.log on the route and see if the test fires that? I added “request” as a package to easily handle that.

Comment: i tried to put console.log in auth.js file to check and see if it shows it after calling the route but still not showing, it did passed the test however i'm not too sure if this really works or is it just working because i specifically put done()

Comment: Here’s a working test that I wrote using mocha/chai, and the request http package which I’d recommend getting. See what you can do with this :)